Ajax Error 400 (Bad Request) in Asp.net core Razor Pages
I have a piece of code that collects the values of the inputs in the HTML page and posts them to a handler using AJAX.
However, when sending by AJAX I get a 400 Bad Request error and the handler is not called.
Please guide me where I am doing wrong ?
$("#sendButton").click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var userId = $("#userId").val();
  var userName = $("#username").val();
  var message = $("#message").val();
  var groupId = $("#groupid").val();
  var attachFile = $("#f").get(0).files;

  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("FileAttach", attachFile);
  formData.append("UserId", userId);
  formData.append("UserName", userName);
  formData.append("Message", message);
  formData.append("GroupId", groupId);
     
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Index?handler=SendMessage",
    data: formData,
    encyType: "multipart/form-data",
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
  });

  $("#message").val('').focus();
    const element = document.getElementById("preChat");
    element.scrollIntoView({ block: "end" });
  });

This is handler code
public class InsertChatViewModel
{
  public string UserId { get; set; }
  public string GroupId { get; set; }
  public string Message { get; set; }
  public string UserName { get; set; }
  public IFormFile FileAttach { get; set; }
}

public IActionResult OnPostSendMessage([FromForm] InsertChatViewModel model)
{
  // It is not called here
  return Page();
}


Everything not cheanged when change ajax parameters

There's nothing wrong with your JS code - aside from encyType is spelled wrong, I assume you mean encType, but even then it should be removed as it's not a valid property of the $.ajax() method options. Have you checked both your middleware and routing logic on the server side? Check your logs to see where the response is being generated on the server side

most likely due to the lack of anti-forgery token.  It's much easier to do something like:    thisForm = document.getElementById(your-form's-id);
var formData = new FormData(thisForm);  I believe Razor pages, by default, will include and check for anti-forgery token.  (Give the  an id attribute if it doesn't have one...)

as Rory suggest use the code:    enctype: "multipart/form-data",

Thank you for your reply, but the problem was related to how to collect and post data and ajax parameters from the html page to the handler in asp.net razor pages.
The full answer is available at this link
